# Display signups on website homepage

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I want to build a landing page where a user can signup with facebook using the [registration plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) and after signing up the total registration count increases by one. 
Thus, the total registration count would be displayed and updated automatically after each user signs up with facebook.

This is pretty similar to this [theme](http://www.themeimpact.com/themeforest-contrapet-petition-and-activism-landing-page-rip/) but only different in a way that we are using facebook login and they have manual login.

How can we execute this kind of functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, I've designed the front end but have not figured out the functionality as I'm quite weak in backend.

Comment: No problem try it you will get success . And if problem persists come here you will get the solution ;)

Comment: Hi Ninad,
Can you guide me on how to bind the fb login data with sql i.e. storing it in sql?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for an answer more sophisticated then working with callbacks from facebook API and save the count of registrations in database or elsewhere to be later retrived and displayed on your homepage?

Comment: Yes, I'm kinda looking for it only.

Comment: But how do we implement that?

Comment: I have already told you how it should be done... as an answer to your question: "How can we execute this kind of functionality?"... Should you add your existing coding here, then it will be possible for us to suggest anything further Unless you are expecting someone to do all the work for you!

Comment: Hi Sidstar,
If you are an individual freelancer and interested in building this single page site, then you can send us your quotation on hardxxxtarget@gmail.com.
Regards